# Почему в JavaScript'е надо ставить отступы в 2 пробела?

Tags: javascript, code-style, jslint

Написал код, проверил через JSLint, он пишет, что надо писать через 2 пробела, а я привык писать через tab, который включает в себя 4 пробела. И смотрю видеокурс по JavaScript'у, там учитель тоже ставит 2 пробела. Почему так?
Никаких споров вызвать не хочу, просто подумал, что 2 пробела правильно, а 4 нет.

Comment: Потому, что они ничего не понимают в жизни. Нужно 4 пробела! (_Ну а вопрос про субъективные предпочтения и потому офтопик._)

Comment: Все знают, что нужно ставить два пробела. Иначе лапша уедет за правую сторону.

Comment: Все знаю, что нужно ставить четыре пробела. =)

Comment: Все знают что число пробелов через Tab настраивается.

Comment: "А оне так привыкши". В сообществе Ruby норма тоже два пробела, это закреплено в community style guide.

Comment: @D-side, _Потому, что они ничего не понимают в жизни. Нужно 4 пробела!_ :-D

Comment: В JS нет никаких **обязательств** использования отступов, как, например, в питоне. Но зато есть куча рекомендаций, которые стандартизируют тип отступов (пробелы или табуляция), их длину (если в пробела; обычно 4, но есть адепты и 2-х), стиль скобок, наименования переменных и много прочего. Что до линта - он проверяет код и на соответствие принятому соглашению. Вы, видимо, забыли указать принятую у вас в команде форму отступов в конфигурации линта. Поправьте и будет ОК.